# Как решить проблему С6993 в С++ при использований OpenMP?

Tags: c++, openmp, parallel

Всем привет. Я хочу использовать

> #pragma omp for

Но во время написаний кода у меня постоянно возникает это ошибка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из за этой ошибки у меня программа работает некорректно. Как решить эту проблему? В гугле не нашел точного ответа. Помогите пожалуйста. Полный код снизу:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <iomanip>

#define N 1000000

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    long long number;
    std::cout << "Введите число: ";
    std::cin >> number;

    long double count = 0;
    while (number > 0)
    {
        number /= 10;
        count++;
    }

    long double numberPi = 0;
    long double temp;

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
    {
#pragma omp for
        for (long long i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            temp = (i + 0.5) * (1.0 / N);
            numberPi += 4.0 / (1.0 + temp * temp);
        }
    }
    std::cout.precision(count - 1);
    std::cout << "number Pi: " << numberPi * (1.0 / (N)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "count: " << count << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а как Вы это видите "работает некорректно"? считает неверно, падает?

Comment: Да, выводят ответ только одного потока. Как убрать эту надпись на совсем?

Comment: Это не ошибка, предупреждение. Не используйте OpenMP или отключите анализ кода.

Comment: Мне надо распараллелить цикл. Я не могу убрать OpenMP.

Comment: а подлинковали библиотеку openmp?

Comment: @KoVadim Включил только компиляцию OpenMP.

Comment: насколько  я помню, без линковки правильной либы от OpenMP оно работать не будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Программа работает некорректно из-за того, что Вы ее некорректно написали. Вот Вы в параллельной секции выполняете такую операцию: `numberPi += 4.0 / (1.0 + temp * temp);` - как компилятор должен это понять? Вы хотите, чтобы в теле цикла для каждого потока создавалась своя копия переменной `numberPi`? И в каком из Ваших потоков должно храниться верное значение? Ответ - точно ни в каком одном. Вы должны указать компилятору, что эта переменная предназначена для суммирования данных из всех потоков. Для этого в OpenMP есть ключевое слово `reduction` с указанием операции: `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)  reduction(+:numberPi)`. Можно указать здесь, можно в прагме с описанием цикла. В итоге должно получиться что-то такое:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <iomanip>

#define N 1000000

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    long long number;
    std::cout << "Введите число: ";
    std::cin >> number;

    long double count = 0;
    while (number > 0)
    {
        number /= 10;
        count++;
    }

    long double numberPi = 0;
    long double temp;

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)  reduction(+:numberPi)
    {
#pragma omp for 
        for (long long i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            temp = (i + 0.5) * (1.0 / N);
            numberPi += 4.0 / (1.0 + temp * temp);
        }
    }
    std::cout.precision(count - 1);
    std::cout << "number Pi: " << numberPi * (1.0 / (N)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "count: " << count << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

В таком виде, при сборке в Mingw-w64 программа работает правильно, в смысле, печатает число `pi` с указанным числом знаков после десятичного разделителя.

Comment: Спасибо Вам что объяснили. Я запустил этот код три раза. И при каждом компиляций дробная часть отличается от предыдущий. Это нормально?

Comment: @LeskhanMuratuly, не должно бы. А при каких number это было? У меня вроде все числа были верные для pi...

Comment: при первым компиляций **number = 1 000 000 000** ответ: **3.14159865** при втором компиляций **number = 1 000 000 000** ответ: **3.14168063**.

Comment: @LeskhanMuratuly, если речь про младшие разряды, то да, тоже отличаются. Насколько я понимаю, данная схема (ряд) не позволяет вычислять пи с бОльшей точностью, чем 3-4 десятичных разряда. В остальных разрядах будет просто мусор, который и меняется при каждом новом запуске программы.

Comment: спасибо Вам большое. Вы мне помогли. Можно еще вопрос? OpenMP запускается только в режиме Debug? Или в режиме Release тоже можно запускать?

Comment: @LeskhanMuratuly, да, конечно OpenMP должен работать при обоих вариантах сборки.